In Swift, why is initialization of lazy static variables thread-safe? How is it implemented?
How does swift implement thread safety of lazy static variable allocation/evaluation? Is there some global lock for all static variable access that all calls go through?

It’s great that statics (which are lazy) offer thread-safe initialization, like globals. But it’s a little frustrating that lazy ivars do not offer thread-safe initialization. (I know that’s not the question here, but I don’t want future readers to stumble across this when searching for “lazy” and “thread-safe” and incorrectly extrapolate from the thread-safe lazy statics and assume the same is true for lazy ivars, because it’s not.)

@Rob hey, I'm sorry, by "ivars" you mean what exactly? It's just that I was under an impression that Swift doesn't have a concept of "ivars", so-- are you talking about an objective-c property that would be lazily initializing an ivar in its implementation?

Sorry, I was using the term loosely. I’m talking about lazy properties. (For those unfamiliar with the “property” vs “ivar” distinction, see Stored Properties and Instance Variables.)

Global variables are initialised using swift_once.

swift_once
@convention(thin) (Builtin.RawPointer, @convention(thin) () -> ()) -> ()

Used to lazily initialize global variables. The first parameter must
point to a word-sized memory location that was initialized to zero at
process start. It is undefined behavior to reference memory that has
been initialized to something other than zero or written to by
anything other than swift_once in the current process's lifetime.
The function referenced by the second parameter will have been run
exactly once in the time between process start and the function
returns.

On Darwin platforms, this is basically a wrapper around dispatch_once_f. As far as I know, dispatch_once_f doesn't use a "global lock". The initialisation of two global variables can happen simultaneously.
